# How can I load Python lambda expressions from YAML files using ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, lambda, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize objects that contain lambda expressions using `ruamel.yaml`. As shown in the example, this yields a `ConstructorError`. How can this be done?

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='unsafe')
yaml.allow_unicode = True
yaml.default_flow_style = False

foo = lambda x: x * 2
yaml.dump({'foo': foo}, sys.stdout)
# foo: !!python/name:__main__.%3Clambda%3E

yaml.load('foo: !!python/name:__main__.%3Clambda%3E')
# ConstructorError: while constructing a Python object
# cannot find '<lambda>' in the module '__main__'
#   in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 6
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not going to work. ruamel.yaml dumps functions (or methods) by making references to the those functions in the source code by referring to their names (i.e. it doesn't try to store the actual code).

Your `lambda` is an anonymous function, so there is no name that can be properly retrieved. In the same way Python's [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) doesn't support `lambda`.

I am not sure if it should be an error to try and dump `lambda`, or that a warning should be in place.

The simple solutions is to make your `lambda`(s) into named functions. Alternatively you might be able to get to the actual code or AST for the lambda and store and retrieve that, but that is going to be more work and might not be portable, depending on what you store.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Storing the actual code would give more readable YAML files but seems almost impossible to de-serialize without assumptions about the global namespace (e.g. imported packages). I'd be fine with storing a reference that de-serializes as long as the Python code does not change. Wouldn't it be possible to serialize lambdas to `!!python/name:module.scope.lambda_n` where `n` refers to which lambda in this scope is referenced?

Comment: Yes there would be more assumptions, but you could still store the module name (as with classes & function), load the module (i.e. getting all reasonalbe  assumptions of the global namespace resolved). IIRC lambdas have a unique id that is not based on their (string) content but differs even between runs on the same Python version. So `!<python/lambda:__main__.x: x * 2>` seems the better way to go. The other thing I would consider is looking at `cloudpickle` and `dill` on how they picke lambdas (and the restrictions of those packages on that)

Comment: Thanks again. Would it be possible to use the lambda serialization and deserialization of `dill` as custom representers and constructors for `ruamel.yaml`?

Comment: Yes, I assume that is possible. You would need to distinguish between "normal" functions and lambdas in the representer, then dill-pickle the lambda to a binary (or better, when dill supports protocol=1, a string representation) and write that as argument to the tag `!!python/lambda'' (and not make the lambda content part of the tag as in my previous comment). A binary representation from pickle would require somewhat more work to encode as ASCII/UTF-8 (e.g. base64 encoding). And you would need the reverse to load it again.